# ajax call not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

An ajax call creating problem. It works fine in browser but through ajax it is not going to called. URL is here http://testbed2.baileyprofile.com/dd-api.php?test=1

When I check it in firefox inspect element console. It sends the request and in about  900 miliseconds or mroe then it give message 200 Ok and url color turn to red. It generate no response at all.

Please any hint what problem it may have.
My code is as under

```
 jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'test' }, function(response) {
        if (response!= '') {
             jQuery('#test-result').html("Restule is generated successfully, copy of result has been sent to your inbox").fadeOut(10000);
             document.getElementById("txtFeedback").value= response;
            //console.log(response.data);
            //alert('POST title: ' + response.data.post_title);
        } else {
            // something didn't go well
            console.log(response.status);
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually url in inspect mode turn red and it does not give any response. It there is any response that will be simple text.

Comment: One think to inform you that this request is going on other server. Mean I have a.com and sending request to b.com. Is it should make any problem?

Comment: [See my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10850833/601179), it's any problem it's **The problem!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

> I have a.com and sending request to b.com. Is it should make any problem?

You're violating the [`Same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't make an ajax from domain `a.com` to `b.com`

Comment: I have use this code it show the message "error"  'code' var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({type: "GET",url: "http://212.124.100.44/gmemo/dd-api.php",data:{'test':'1'} })
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { alert("error "+ textStatus); })

Comment: So how I can solve this problem. I need to send request to other server and need data from it.

Comment: @nbhatti2001. What about `<iframe>` or `jsonp`?

Comment: let me explain my scenario. I will give test on server A and send that data to server B that server have to prepare result and send it to the user and send back the quick result which I have show on current screen. but I do not want to change screen. Please help how I can achive this?

Comment: @nbhatti2001. You can use one of two ways: `iframe\ jsonp` google it for a tutorial. If you have problems with it, you should ask another question. I can't teach you a new "technology" in comments or even in an answer.

Comment: I invoke an ajax to local page then get data from other site by calling get_file_contents() fucntion and send data by post. This resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data parameters should be within ''. Try it and it should work

```
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {'action': 'test' }, function(response) {
        if (response!= '') {
             jQuery('#test-result').html("Restule is generated successfully, copy of result has been sent to your inbox").fadeOut(10000);
             document.getElementById("txtFeedback").value= response;
            //console.log(response.data);
            //alert('POST title: ' + response.data.post_title);
        } else {
            // something didn't go well
            console.log(response.status);
        }
    });
```